# Kill excel process which was started by a specific application

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have a console application, in which I open many excel applications to do some treatments. At the end I want to kill all the Excel processes opened by this console application. So, I'm using a code like this :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
for (int i = 0; i < procs.Length; i++)
{
    if (procs[i].ProcessName == "EXCEL")
    {
        procs[i].Kill();
    }
}
```

but this code closes all excel applications in my computer including ones which are not opened by my application. 
My question is, how can I modify this code to close only the excel apps opened by my console application?

Comment: Add some text file at some arbitrary location ( eg. "C:\Windows\Temp\meExcelProcesses.txt" ) then upon starting process that kills those, just read process ids from that file.

Comment: How about closing the Excel over the object rather than killing the proccess?

Comment: Hi @FatTony I tried to close all my excel apps, workbooks and workbooks, but i'm opening like 15 apps at the same time that in the end i have 2 excel processes which still opened. I have something like this foreach excel app opened:
excelWorkBook2.Close(true);                               
                                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkBook2);
                                    excelWorkBook2 = null;
                                    excelApplication.Quit();
                                    excelApplication = null;

Comment: Hi @m.rogalski, its a good idea, but how can i get excel processes id?  (i can directly use a list for example or a table in my code to store these id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose doing some wrapper on ( Excel ) `Process` on which you could call `Close` when you're done with it.

```
public class ExcelProcess
{
    Process m_Process;
    public ExcelProcess(/* parameters of your choice */)
    {
        // instantiate process and assign it to the m_Process variable
    }

    public ExcelProcess(int id)
    {
        // this will instantiate process object and hook to the process with specified process id
        m_Process = Process.GetProcessById(id);
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        m_Process.Kill();
    }

    public override ToString()
    {
        // this will return process id as a string value
        return m_Process.Id.ToString();
    }
}
```

Having object like the one above you can :
1. move "instances" around from project to project by serializing list/array of these to some text file ( as `.ToString()` )
2. have direct control over the process ( each of `ExcelProcess` can have it's own IPC to communicate with external process, you can redirect streams from and to process ) which would be handled by this object
3. **get confused** when someone else closes the application which is currently linked to that object.

Extending above points, Let's assume that user **CANNOT** close your application that is hooked to `ExcelProcess`.

You can create a holder object/field which then can be serialzed :

```
List<ExcelProcess> m_ExcelProcesses;
```

Add any process to it.

```
foreach(var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("excel"))
{
    m_ExcelProcesses.Add(new ExcelProcess(process.Id));
}
```

Now let's say you want to close them in another application :

```
byte[] nl = new byte[2] { 0x0D, 0x0A }; // new line
using (FileStream fs = File.Create("C:\SomeArbitrary\PathToFile.txt"))
{
    foreach(ExcelProcess proc in m_Processes)
    {  
        byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(int.Parse(proc.ToString()));
        fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        fs.Write(nl, 0, nl.Length);
    }
}
```

After that in your new process that is responsible for closing those just read all of the values and rewrite the file (or delete it).

```
byte[] pidBytes = new byte[4]; // we stored int which is 4 bytes wide;
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("C:\SomeArbitrary\PathToFile.txt"))
{
    while(fs.CanRead)
    {
        fs.Read(pidBytes, 0, sizeof(int));
        m_Processes.Add(new ExcelProcess(BitConverter.ToInt32(pidBytes, 0)));
        fs.ReadByte(); // CR - 0x0D
        fs.ReadByte(); // LF - 0x0A
    }
}
```

Comment: oh thank you so much @m.rogalski, it's exactly what i'm searching for! Great explanation

Answer (score 2):

Try using().

```
  using(var newExcelObject = ...){
               // your code here
  }
  // closes the object you intialised above
```

Once it goes out of scope, it will automatically close the process. This would be the easiest and a good practice to close the excel processes.

Otherwise you can close/dispose the objects manually instead of killing processes.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I'm using this :          
 excelWorkBook2.Close(true);
 targetSheet2 = null;                                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkBook2);
 excelWorkBook2 = null;
 excelApplication.Quit();
 excelApplication = null;

But it's not closing all the files, I'm opening 14 applications in my code, at the end I have 2 apps which are not closed, that's why I'm directly trying to kill these processes

Comment: @LaalaDjelouah if it's failing to close, that means you're leaking references to things you should have cleaned up. It does close if you clean up correctly, but it's hard to get it right. Often using a 3rd party library is easier.

Comment: I second @Ian suggestion. Have you tried using LinqToExcel instead. Its much less messy. Heres a link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659643/Csharp-Query-Excel-and-CSV-Files-Using-LinqToExcel